# Fill textbox with info from address bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that needs the user to input a promotional code from another page, depending on what choices they make. Now I'm not sure how this is done....or even if it's possible with my lack of knowledge. But I'd like to give it a go.

What I'm trying to do is make the promotional code they click on, link to the registration page, (which basically only asks which code they want to use) but autocomplete the promotional code field textbox with the code that represents their choice. (just so they don't have to copy and paste really.) Heres the form code.

```
<input type="text" id="registration_code" name="c[registration_code]" {if $badCode}value="{$badCode}"{/if} size="30" maxlength="30" class="field" />
```

I've tried....

[www.mywebsite.com/registration.php?id="registration_code"&name="c[mypromocode]"](http://www.mywebsite.com/registration.php?id=%22registration_code%22&name=%22c%5Bmypromocode%5D%22)

AND..

[www.mywebsite.com/registration.php?id=registration_code&name=mypromocode](http://www.mywebsite.com/registration.php?id=registration_code&name=mypromocode)

I've also tried a few others.... I'm probably barking up the wrong tree, but I'm sure I've seen this done somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If the url is generated by JavaScript then you need to format the string correctly:

```
var url="www.mywebsite.com/registration.php?id="+registration_code+"&name="+c[mypromocode];
```

It the url is generated by php then use:

```
$url="www.mywebsite.com/registration.php?id=".$registration_code."&name=".$c[mypromocode];
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply...So I create my basic blurb page in html, but link any images in php?

Comment: Getting back to this problem, & thinking about it, the url isn't yet generated by anything, although I was going to use html, such as I was attempting above. So far I have created a basic page containing the image with the promo details (there'll be half a dozen or so later), but now need to find the syntax for the links which will complete the 'promocode' textbox on the registration page.  If I use Javascript and the example above. What is the other syntax that calls the 'var url'. I am thinking that the above example is only the declaration?