# save a text object to clipboard when clicking on another object

Tags: image, focus, clipboard

Is it possible to click on a linked image and save the image 'name' or 'id' to the clipboard. Then on the new page set the focus to the text box and paste the image 'name' or 'id'into it?
Thsi question is related to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182969/fill-textbox-with-info-from-address-bar), but I'm coming at it from another angle.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Please tell us more about your application environment (language, platform).*

I suppose you are talking about HTML (web) navigation between two pages. The clipboard is not the right way to pass information from one page to another ! Forget it !

The clipboard is a buffer, at the exclusive intention of the user. The clipboard must only be accessed from commands on explicit user demands (cut, copy, paste, shorcuts or buttons like "copy this to clipboard"...). Its use is totally inapropriate here, even if it would be possible to code it the way you described.

Assuming *pageA* and *pageB* are two pages of your own application;

**In pageA**

You should generate image links more or less like this:

```
<a href="pageB?id=1"><img src="images/image1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="pageB?id=2"><img src="images/image2.jpg"/></a>
```

**In pageB**

You will receive *id* in the URL parameters. It is easy to do, but code depends the you language and tools you intend to use.

Comment: Ok, Understood about the 'clipboard'.  Website is on a linux server running Apache. I am contemplating some additional code to the existing html page. First page is pricing images, second is registration. Pricing details are in image form.  Registration expects a code to be entered which the user gets from the Pricing page, and I'd like to make it a single click operation to get the code straight into the text area on the Reg' page.Thanks